# When are changes locally merged with `git checkout`?

Tags: git

1. Suppose I am on the master branch. There is a file in my working directory called "master.txt" that contains the single text line "asdf".
2. Suppose I then `git checkout f364f96d34fb2af20dbd8cccd91a83a1e277bcfe`, which takes me to an older commit on the master branch than HEAD.
3. I then edit the file "master.txt" (which still, at this point, has the line "asdf") by deleting the line "asdf".
4. I then `git checkout master`.
5. It appears that my `master.txt` is still empty (i.e.,  no "asdf)!

**Question:** Is this the way things are supposed to work? Reading a textbook on git, I thought changes were only locally merged on `git checkout` if no conflicts arose. But deleting "asdf" creates a conflict, no?

Answer (score 1):

You never committed the change you made to the `master.txt` file.  Just because you moved your `HEAD` to a different commit, and then moved back to the `master` branch indicator doesn't mean that any commits will implicitly take place.

Long story short, you never committed the change you made to the text file, therefore you wouldn't see that behavior you were expecting.

Your step 4, when you went to checkout master, you should've received the following error:

```
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        master.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

You can always force a checkout of master to discard these changes:

```
$ git checkout master -f
```

But this makes me think you never saved your changes to `master.txt` when you deleted that string.

You could've taken two approaches here:

### Don't commit your changes to the detached HEAD commit

In this case, your changes would be lost if you did a force checkout back to master.

### Commit your changes to the detached HEAD commit

You could've committed your changes to the detached HEAD commit, and that would've given you a warning when trying to non-forcefully checkout master again:

```
$ git checkout master
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  10038c2 commit4

If you want to keep it by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 10038c2

Switched to branch 'master'
```

Git is telling us that the commit hash belonging to that is "left behind" (not tied to any branch).

Answer (score 1):

When you checkout a commit without specifying paths, the *working tree* is updated to match the contents of the tree of that commit, but the *current index* (cache/staging area) is left unchanged.

What you see is an extension of that behavior:  even if you don't add the change to the index, git will reapply it on top of the new working tree so that you don't lose it.

You can then checkout `HEAD` with the path of the file to remove the change, or add it to the index and commit it.

The [reference documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) mentions that "conflicts" occur if you have local modifications on a file that is different in the trees of `HEAD` and of the target commit.  In your case, both versions of your `master.txt` file contain `asdf`, only your working tree has it empty.  Hence, there is no conflict.

If you were to add a commit with `master.txt` containing `foo`, checkout the commit with `master.txt` having `asdf` and do the same operations you described, git would prevent you from subsequently checking out the second commit again.

Comment: Note: I edited the answer to correct an oversight on my part. It's *technically* a different answer.